In what scope do OpenGL binding points exist?
OpenGL allows for the creation of Uniform Buffer Objects. Each UBO lives at a certain binding point (index) from which it can be picked up by a shader (associating a binding point with a block index). But I was wondering, at what scope does this index matter? Does each renderpass have its own set of binding point indices? Or does the whole application have one global list of binding points, shared by all UBOs?
If some why isn't there some glGenBindingPoint like there is for texture and vbo ids?
And how do I dynamically allocate binding points if I delete a UBO? Do I just pick the next available binding point index or do I not reuse indices?
Edit:Apperantly there are only 90s total UBO supported across the entire application. So definetly reuse indices. Although that seems crazy low to me.

OpenGL has no concept of a "renderpass". There are only draw calls.
UBO binding indices are, like all other bindings, state that is part of the OpenGL context. That is their "scope". They're basically a context-global array of references to buffer objects. You don't "allocate" global arrays; they're always there.
A buffer object bound to a particular index will remain bound to that index until a different buffer is bound to that index (or 0 is bound) or when the buffer is deleted.

so just increase the UBO binding index without a care in the world then?

@user2741831: What are you talking about? There are limits to binding indices. Why would you be trying to "increase" them? You bind the buffer to the index your shader is set to use. That's how it works. If you switch shaders and need to use different UBOs, you bind a new set of UBOs based on what indices the new shader uses.

You said theres a global set of binding point indices. As I destroy and create UBO's in my application (For example creating new Materials, which each needs a new UBO for Material properties) I need to assign a new binding point index for each of them. So I was wondering how I effectively allocate those indices. Do I need to reuse them (from a deleted material vbo) or can I just have increment the binding point index, leaving gaps where deleted Material VBO's used to be

@user1510024: "I need to assign a new binding point index for each of them" Absolutely not. A buffer does not need a unique binding point; you bind a buffer to a UBO binding point when you render. Once you've finished rendering with it, it need not be bound and you can bind something else to that UBO binding point. Ideally, you sort your rendering draw order so that you only change UBO bindings when you need to (parameters shared between multiple programs can go into the same buffer that doesn't change), but you are expected to bind different buffers during rendering.
